# Link to resource by internal link only?

Tags: uri

I've been asked if there's any way I can link to a resource on a site without making that resource visible via an external link.

The client wants a price list only available via a link on a page on the site itself. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the *link* will be visible, but if it's a link to something nobody else is authorized to see then only authorized users would be able to see it.

For example, you might link to something which requires authentication.  When anybody clicks on that link, they're prompted for that authentication and are validated before the content is returned to them.  If only this particular client is authorized, nobody else would see the content.

You might even link to a URI which is only *physically* accessible by that particular client.  For example, a file on that client's machine.  Something like this, for example:

```
<a href="file:///c:/Data/file.pdf">click here</a>
```

Only that client *has* that file, so the link would fail for anybody else.

Either way, the *link* isn't the issue.  The access to the resource *being linked to* is the issue.  As long as that access is protected, nobody else can see it.

Of course, as an added UX concern you might also conditionally only *display* the link if that same authorization is available.  You'd still want to protect the resource itself, since otherwise it would just be "security through obscurity", but you should also really only *show* the link if the user is expected to be able to access it.